# Writing Recursive Method ; Reverse Word

Tags: java

create a java program that will ask a user to input a word and reverse it using the recursive method. It should ask the user to try again y or n

I have missing code I don't know what should I put on line 14.

```
package reverseword;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tryAgain = "Y";
        do{
        String reversedString = "";
        System.out.print("Enter string to reversed: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        reversedString = reverseString(input);
        System.out.println("Reversed String : "+reversedString);
        System.out.println("Try again? enter \"Y/N\": ");
        tryAgain = input.next();

        }while(!tryAgain.equals("N"));

    } 
    public static String reverseString(String input){
        if(input.isEmpty())
            return input;
        return reverseString(input.substring(1)) + input.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Enter string to reversed:lala
Reversed String : alal
Try again? enter \"Y/N\": Y
Enter string to reversed:

//if the answer is no:

Enter string to reversed:lala
Reversed String : alal
Try again? enter \"Y/N\": N
Bye!

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: What's the problem? Which is line 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that 14th line is

```
tryAgain = input.next();
```

It does not compile because input is String, you meant to use Scanner sc. Try this:

```
tryAgain = sc.next();
```

Comment: after the line System.out.print("Try Again? Y/N: "); I put 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ans=scan.next();
what should I put under that? cause It just do infinite loop

Comment: You don't need to create new scanner. Just use previous one. Just use tryAgain = sc.next();